# Spring MVC - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/demo/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to create a small web application. When I try to hit a URL that seems to be mapped properly in my controller, I get a 404. I'm trying to hit /projectname/test- and this is what shows in the log when I attempt to do that:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/demo/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

I've seen a lot of similar questions being asked, but none of the suggested fixes worked for me. I'm using Spring MVC and the server can't seem to resolve the URL coming in through the browser. The strange thing is that "/projectname" works great, but "/projectname/test" won't seem to work at all. The JSPs are all in the same directory (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/) with the following names:

- home.jsp
- test.jsp
- userInfo.jsp

Here is my code:

pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
 <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
 <name>demo</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
  <java-version>1.6</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
    
  <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency> 
  
  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>
    
  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
 
  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>        
 </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- Processes application requests -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
 
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven/>

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.demo" />
 
 
 
</beans:beans>
```

HomeController.java :

```html
package com.springapp.demo;

import java.util.Locale;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@Controller
public class HomeController {
 
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
 
 /**
  * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
  */
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
  logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
  
  return "home";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String userInfo(Model model, @RequestParam(value="userName")String userName, @RequestParam(value="gender")String gender ) {
    
  model.addAttribute("userName", userName);
  model.addAttribute("gender", gender);
  
  return "userInfo";
 }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String test(Model model) {
  
  return "test";
 }
 
}
```

Any ideas? Is there more info I need to provide? Thanks!

Comment: My recommendation. Stay away from XML-s. Look into Spring Boot if you want a small web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior you see is expected one. Your `HomeController` class doesn't have a mapping for `/demo` URI, only `/user`, `/test` and `/`.

UPD: After I have seen the question update, I concluded that you refer `demo` as a context descriptor and probably requesting it like

`http://localhost:8080/demo/test`

If my assumption is correct, the most probable cause of your troubles is a mismatch of context descriptor you're using in browser and the one at which application is really deployed. You may want to try accessing it like

`http://localhost:8080/test`

or

`http://localhost:8080/appServlet/test`

If that works (i.e. `return "test";` is invoked) than this is the issue. If you want other application name then `appServlet`, you should take some actions that depend on application server you use, for example you may want to rename `.war` file after build, or change IDE settings if you deploy for there, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your assumption is correct- I'm using /demo/test to try and hit that page. I've now tried /test and /appServlet/test as well as you suggested, and still had the same issue.

Comment: @RemziIbrahimZayid Ok, can you describe the way you deploy the application? The name can also be `demo-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, based on your `pom.xml`.

Comment: The thing is that just /demo/ works fine, so I'd be surprised if its an issue with that name, but I'll certainly give it a shot. I'm using STS (Spring Tool Suite) to deploy all of this code. By default, this uses: VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.9 
as its server. Its integrated with tomcat I believe. The only settings I changed on the server configuration are the ports, which are now:

Tomcat admin port: 8140
HTTP/1.1 : 8141

I'm using localhost:8141 to try and hit these URLs.

Comment: @RemziIbrahimZayid I can also suggest to take a look at Spring deployment logs, it reports all registered mappings when application context is being started. Check if `/demo/test` is there.

Comment: Got it fixed! Thanks for all of your help. After looking in the logs, I saw that the pattern for that mapping wasn't coming up. So I checked the war file and saw that the .Class file for my controller wasn't updating. I manually re-built and voila, solved! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to add the below mapping:

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/"/> -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory  -->
     <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>  

    <!-- View Handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
<beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
<beans:property name="mediaTypes">
<beans:map>
<beans:entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
<beans:entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
<beans:entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
<beans:entry key="less" value="text/html"/>
</beans:map>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="viewResolvers">
<beans:list>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/> 
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/"/> 
</beans:bean> 
 </beans:list> 
 </beans:property> 
 </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access /demo, but as I see in your Controller, there is no such URI Template. You have root "/", "/user" and "/test".

Comment: So sorry! I edited the original post. "demo" is the project name. I'm trying to get to /demo/test

Comment: Everything in your Controller and jsp files looks fine. Try this:Stop server.
right click in your project -> Maven clean after that Maven install. Start the server and try again :)